# mosquitto 1.4.14 not supporting web socket in windows and code is not working

Tags: javascript, windows, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I am working mqtt and i made a webscript and i want to use it with mosquiito 1.4.14, but its not working with web socket support, I tried to put WEBSOCKET and port number in mosquitto.conf file but its still not working..

I had error WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1883/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED...

I checked my code by replacing the online broker address and port number it`s working... so where to find the web socket support broker or how to make mosquitto to work with web socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pre-built versions of mosquitto for Windows available for download from the mosquitto website do **NOT** include websocket support.

The only way to get websocket support on Windows with mosquitto is to build it yourself as described in this Internet of Things Stack Exchange post:

https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/how-to-enable-websockets-on-mosquitto-running-on-windows/